# Trouble Understanding Flow Of Rock Paper Scissors Program

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

I apologize for asking another rock paper scissors question.  This is my first time learning to code and I'd rather understand why the flow of my code doesn't work, then to copy and paste the right answer.

The way I see it is that I am calling game(); which then calls playerSelection(), computerPlay(), and finally playRound(). Those variables are then put into playRound() which determines the output base don the if/else statement.  Game() is then looped four more times until it ends and the final totals are logged to the console.

So far every time I run the game, it always ends with five draws and a score of 0 for both player and computer.  I've been fiddling with it for a while and it seems like every little thing I do "breaks" the program.  Any insight is GREATLY appreciated!

```js
let playerChoice;
let computerChoice;
let i = 0;
       
function game(){
    
    for (i; i < 5; i++) {
        function playerSelection() {
            let playerChoice = prompt("Rock paper scissors?");
            return playerChoice;
            }
            
    playerSelection();
        

           function computerPlay () {
               let computerChoice = ["rock", "paper","scissors"];
                return computerChoice[Math.floor(Math.random()*computerChoice.length)];
            }

    computerPlay();
   
    playRound();
        
        function playRound(playerChoice, computerChoice) {
            let playerScore = 0;
            let compScore = 0;

            if (playerChoice == computerChoice) {
                console.log("Draw!")
            } else if (playerChoice == "rock" && computerChoice == "scissors"){
                console.log("You Win!")
                playerScore++;
            } else if (playerChoice == "paper" && computerChoice == "rock"){
                    console.log("You Win!")
                    playerScore++;
            } else if (playerChoice == "scissors" && computerChoice == "paper"){
                console.log("You Win!")
                playerScore++;
            } else {
                console.log("You Lose!")
                compScore++;
            }
            console.log(playerScore);
            console.log(compScore);
            return;
            }

    }
}


game();

if (playerScore > compScore) {
    console.log("Congratulations! You won the game!")
    } else {
    console.log("You lost the game!")
}
```

Comment: You should probably rephrase your question to be less open ended and instead describe what behavior you're seeing versus what you'd expect. That sort of question is more likely to have repeat value for posterity as someone might find it from Google and it might help them. This would result in less downvotes and more answers.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're always seeing *Draw!* is because you're not using the return value of the two functions `playerSelection()` and `computerPlay()` to override the value of `playerChoice` and `computerChoice`.